# Wildcard at end of principal for s3 bucket

Tags: amazon-s3, terraform

I want to allow roles within an account that have a shared prefix to be able to read from an S3 bucket. For example, we have a number of roles named `RolePrefix1`, `RolePrefix2`, etc, and may create more of these roles in the future. We want all roles in an account that begin with `RolePrefix` to be able to access the S3 bucket, without having to change the policy document in the future.

My terraform for bucket policy document is as below:

```py
data "aws_iam_policy_document" "bucket_policy_document" {
  statement {
    effect = "Allow"
    actions = ["s3:GetObject"]

    principals = {
      type = "AWS"
      identifiers = ["arn:aws:iam::111122223333:role/RolePrefix*"]
    }

    resources = ["${aws_s3_bucket.bucket.arn}/*"]
  }
}
```

This gives me the following error:

`Error putting S3 policy: MalformedPolicy: Invalid principal in policy`.

Is it possible to achieve this functionality in another way?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You cannot use wildcard along with the ARN in the IAM principal field. You're allowed to use just `"*"`.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_elements_principal.html

> When you specify users in a Principal element, you cannot use a wildcard (*) to mean "all users". Principals must always name a specific user or users.

Workaround:

Keep `"Principal":{"AWS":"*"}` and create a condition based on ARNLike etc as they accept user ARN with wildcard in condition.

Example:

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/how-to-restrict-amazon-s3-bucket-access-to-a-specific-iam-role/

Comment: Could you please provide an example condition statement based on ARNLike? There isn't any in the link provided.

Comment: @yerzhan7 For posterity: `StringLike = { aws:PrincipalArn = [ "arn:aws:iam::*:role/<ROLE_NAME>" ] }`

Comment: Reformatted example:  `"Condition": {"StringLike": { "aws:PrincipalArn": [ "arn:aws:iam::*:role/<ROLE_NAME>" ] }`