# How to add a wild-card like principal role in an IAM Trust Policy?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, aws-iam-policy

I am trying to allow role A to assume role B. For testing purposes, both roles have AWS Administrator Access out of the box, with the ability to allow access to every resource with all permissions.

For role A to assume role B, role B must contain role A in the trust policy, like so:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        #Role A 
        "AWS": "arn:aws:sts::1234567890:assumed-role/ubuntu/botocore-session-xxx"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
  ]
}
```

For my particular case, the assumed role contains a nomenclature of botocore-session-xxx appended at the end, where "xxx" will always be a random set of numbers.

My issue is, because these sessions are dynamic and the xxx is randomly generated, I cannot manually input the corresponding digits of the actual botocore-session that is being used in the trust policy, it would not be feasible for myself.

Instead, I tried going for a wildcard approach like so:

```
{
 "Version": "2012-10-17",
 "Statement": [
   {
     "Effect": "Allow",
     "Principal": {
       #Role A 
       "AWS": "arn:aws:sts::1234567890:assumed-role/ubuntu/botocore-session-*"
     },
     "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
   }
 ]
}
```

But the above is an invalid policy and does not work in AWS. Did I screw myself over with this approach? How can Role B contain an "open" trust policy to allow for Role A: assumed-role/test-ubuntu/botocore-session-xxx , considering that "xxx" will always be a set of random generated numbers?

Appreciate some guidance on this one.

Comment: I think this is similar to [Wildcard at the end of principal for s3 bucket](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56678539/12326605). You can try using `aws:PrincipalArn` condition key in the trust policy and see if it works for you.